# Simultaneous reads from Mongo using mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, node-async

I have a situation where I have to gather data from three different collections and bundle it together ( there are no joins to be done here) and send it to the client.

Although I have what I think is an elegant solution, I want to ask the community whether there is a cleaner way of performing this operation ?

I am using mongoose as a data modeling layer:

```
  async.parallel([
      function(callback) {

        ForecastModel.find({facebookId: req.query.playerId}, function(err, result) {
          callback(err, result);
        });

      },
      function(callback) {

        ScoreModel.find({facebookId: req.query.playerId}, function(err, result) {
          callback(err, result);
        });

      },
      function(callback) {

        FollowModel.findOne({facebookId: req.query.playerId}, function(err, result) {
          callback(err, result);
        });

      }
    ],
    function(err, results) {
      var playerInfo = {};
      playerInfo.forecasts = results[0];
      playerInfo.score = results[1][0];
      playerInfo.followModel = results[2];

      res.send(playerInfo);
    });
```

Comment: Did you try [async.map](https://github.com/caolan/async#map)? Which basically "concatenates" the results. There are "series" alternates to it, but the default is "parallel". If the problem is the results being do large then you can alternately work with "streams" combining into writing to an "ouput" stream. But the first just needs one which edit and deletes some lines.

Comment: Mongoose can do the joins for you as far as I remember. Found it: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html